# How to receive "hidden field" values in second jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, scriptlet

I have page1.jsp where hidden fields are included.
Following is the code:

```
<form action = "page2.jsp" method = "post" id = "hiddenValuesForm">
<input type = "hidden" name = "userData" value="" id = "useDataID">
<input type = "SUBMIT" id= "submitUserData" style= "display:none" >
</form>
```

In page2.jsp , I can get the hidden field values using the below code:

```
<%
String hiddenField = request.getParameter("userData");
%>
```

Is there any way I can  assign the value of "userData" to a jquery variable in page2.jsp similar to the scriplet variable "hiddenField".

Comment: is really not hard to research

Comment: You can use `params` implicit object to get the value from query parameter. `var userData = "${params.userData}";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *generate* a javascript variable in page2.jsp:

```
<script>
var myUserData="<%=request.getParameter("userData")%>"
</script>
```

(I put enclosing quotes assuming it is a string.)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to put the value in a hidden input on page2 and use jQuery to retrieve it. Or if page2 is a partial view in page 1, you can access the original hidden input in page 1 using jQuery

Sorry I'm on my phone so I won't post any code right now